# Symfony2 sessions aren't persisting after page load

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having an issue with a Symfony2 site. I've got the codebase running on a production server, which is absolutely fine but I'm trying to get another developer started on the project and we're running into issues getting the build up and running. The environments are pretty much identical, the developer is using a Vagrant instance, the same provisioning on that instance was used to provision an EC2 instance on AWS.

When a form is submitted the action goes through and stores values to the session using Symfonys session handler before redirecting to another action which makes up step two of the form. I can see in Xdebug that the values are being added to the global $_SESSION variable, however when I reach the next break point in the second action the $_SESSION variable is missing the content that it had on the previous action. I'm not clearing the session anywhere, and as I said it works fine on production.

It's almost as if Symfony isn't storing session data between page loads, does anybody have any ideas?

**Things tried**

- Adding cookie domain to the config
- Setting permissions to 777 (just to test)
- PHP Versions are one minor iteration apart (5.4.28-1 vs
  5.4.27-1)

Comment: are you persisting your sessions to disk or a db?

Comment: Sessions are being persisted to disk as far as I know, I've not configured anything special so the session stuff should be as it is out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue after upgrading from PHP 5.4.27 to PHP 5.4.28, and in my case it was related to this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66171

Quote from the description:

> Second problem: When the session.save_path is a directory that
>   everyone can write into (like on Debian), even if it's not possible to
>   find the IDs of existing sessions, a local attacker can just create a
>   new session file with malicious session data, chmod it to 666 and
>   access any webapp hosted on the system with the session ID he chose.
>   The webapp then opens the session file and treats it as if it had
>   created it. My fix: fstat() the session, check the uid that created
>   the file. If it's neither the result of getuid() nor uid 0, ignore the
>   existing file.

They now compare the owner of the session files with the user executing the PHP script, and if the uids do not match, the session file will be ignored. 
In my case, the apache user had write access to the session files through group rights, but because the uid did not match, PHP would not load the session files.

Have a look at your session files (you can find the save path in your php.ini file), and make sure the owner of the files match the user attempting to access them.

Comment: Thank you so so much, me and my colleague are eternally indebted to you. We damn near started a religion in your name.

Just a note here. We're using Vagrant to run a LAMP stack which has Symfony2 on it. To get around the user issues we just changed the session path (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/sessions_directory.html) to /tmp.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you, it took me a couple of hours to figure this out too.